# Firefox 42000x280 image not showing? What are Firefox's maximum image dimensions?

Tags: html, image, firefox, mozilla

I am trying to display a 42000x280 2.46mb image that will not display in Firefox, but it works in Chrome + IE. The image can be found at http://tpupower.net/tron2.gif

The image is made from an animated gif and I saved it with PHP's imagegif(). Could this be a color profile error? How would I check that?

The image won't open in Photoshop either, I don't know if its because of the dimensions or what. The error it gives is below.

"Could not complete your request because of a problem with the file-format interface."

Comment: That file opens fine in Paint.Net and Gimp 2.8...

Comment: Yea that's working for me too but Firefox for some reason just shows a the broken image icon.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure the file was OK, you didn't state that explicitly in your question :-)

Comment: It is true that firefox can't show this, If I were you I would make a new css for firefox alone. If you use this method you can catch the error and fix it

Comment: @STP38 How will a new CSS fix the problem of the gif file not being shown? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @rene How to use a css file for different browser:http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/excludecss.shtml


You can make a specific css for firefox, if you do you should change the width or height of the gif file. There is no better solution for your problem I think.

Comment: @rene there are more likely question as yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694937/firefox-show-broken-images?rq=1

Comment: If Photoshop can't open it then it sounds like your file isn't valid, PS generally has no problems with files of sizes like that.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to save this image as PNG, with `imagepng()` instead of `imagegif()`?

Answer (score 0):

It is a fact that firefox and photoshop can't open it,you should use GIMP(GNU manipulation program) and scale image..GIMP is free and open source image manipulator.you can scale or decrease quality of image.I am sure it will open in GIMP.

you can download and get more info. from link:
http://www.gimp.com/

hope this will be helpful.